# Two SQL Server Instances

Tags: sql-server, ssrs-2016

I have a server running SQL Server 2014, Enterprise Edition, with many large databases. I am currently using SSRS 2014 to create on-premises reports from this data.

I really like the new features of SSRS 2016. My question is: can I install SQL Server Express 2016 (for free) on the same server, just to utilize the new 2016 SSRS, while my data remains in the SQL Server 2014 databases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can use express to read data from any of the "higher" edition SQL Servers (like enterprise or standard), which I would assume that is what you're planning to do.

Otherwise you could install as many SSRS servers you would like for free. See [Features Supported by the Editions of SQL Server 2016](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993%28v=sql.130%29.aspx#SSRS)

Comment: But I already use SSRS 2014 on a server to read data on many other servers, each running different versions of SQL Server. Shouldn't it be doable to read data on the same server, too?

Comment: @controller But your current SSRS edition is standard (or enterprise)? And like the table says, that can connect to any edition of SQL Server.

Comment: Current edition is enterprise. But shouldn't express with advanced tools be able to connect to any other server?

Comment: @controller Did you look at the link? To my mind it clearly says `Express` and in enterprise it says `All SQL Server editions`